# Automatically passing a value from the command line to th "while-read" loop?

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, terminal

ISSUE: Currently implementing a script that can perform an action on ONE item or a FILE/LIST of items,  provided by the user. The problem currently is that when I attempt to perform the action on a list using the "while-read" format, my script prompts me to re-enter the FILE/LIST.

GOAL: I want the user to be able to run the script and enter a the FILE/LIST via the traditional `[command] [option] [target/argument]` format. Without having to be prompted a second time for the `[target/argument]` FILE, to initialize the `while-read`loop

CODE:

```
printf -v TODAY 'scan_%(%F)T' -1 # e.g. scan_2017-11-27
OUTFILE=${host:-$TODAY}

HOSTNAME=$host
while read $HOSTNAME 
do 
        scan $HOSTNAME

done | tee $OUTFILE
```

Comment: Are you looking for a for loop, like `for HOSTNAME in "$@"; do ...; done`?

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to have the command accept multiple targets/arguments as part of the command, instead of accepting them as input after the command runs?

Comment: I don't think `while read $HOSTNAME` is doing what you think it is doing. Using shell debug `set -vx` (and `set +vx` for turning off) may help you understand what your script is currently doing. The typical form for reading lines from a file is `while read line ; do echo "something with $line" ; done < inputFile.txt` . Add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, and paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix any errors there, and update your Q above with the fixed code. Good luck.

Comment: Yes the goal is to have the command accept multiple arguments from a text file